# Cisco switch:change mac type from dynamic to static in console

Tags: cisco, switch, update, mac-address

How to change mac from static to dynamic in mac-address-table (switch)?I find [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/MACAddress.html) official source but still not understand what options I must choose.

Something like this:

switch(config)# mac-address-table static 12ab.47dd.ff89 vlan 3 interface fastethernet 2/1 auto-learn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change a static entry to dynamic. Just delete the static entry and the switch will add its own dynamic entry when that host sends a frame.

Use the "no" syntax to delete an address. E.g.:

```
no mac-address-table static 12ab.47dd.ff89 vlan 3
```